# Unwinding a brushed (AC, 120v 60hz) motor to the tune of one turn, what for to gain length

Tags: motor, ac, repair, brushed-dc-motor

I am sure this applies to most if not all brushed motors, however to be specific I am working with a 1990's handheld vacuum cleaner (you know the ones, powered roller brush, bag, usually black/red, much chooch).

Both ends of one of the two windings on the motor have become detached (don't ask) from the "holder" which attaches a brush on one side, the other is a similar situation except it bridges a conductor (line) to the end of the winding wire.

Both of these wires are very taut, and do not have enough reach because of the breakage to be able to re-attached via the little slot/slit that it gets pulled down into in order to bridge the connection. I first concluded that I would perhaps attempt to create more length by attaching some more wire to the existing ends, but thinking about that it seems it would be rather too uninsulated and a bit too rigged for my taste when dealing with high voltage AC.

So I planned a heist to gain my much desired bit of copper, the plan is to steal it from itself! That is, to unwind a turn on both sides in order to have plenty of length. However my intuition tells me that this may upset the delicate electromagnetic balance going on here, and perhaps it may necessitate doing the same to the winding on other side of the motor. It also does not sit well that I would be chopping off a couple inches on each side just to gain a couple more millimeters of wire, not to mention the performance ramifications are unknown to me.

Are my thoughts on this so far on track, or is there a better way of tackling this problem that I have not thought of (very likely)?

I am not trying to win any races with this motor however any details on performance ramifications if I proceed doing this planned would be appreciated. Most importantly, if I do so, is balance/repeating this process to the other side absolutely necessary?

Comment: The coils should be many hundreds of turns, so reducing by one should have only a tiny effect. Assuming the turns aren't glued together. Unfortunately device repair is off topic here though.

Comment: oh sorry this is my first post. where would be the appropriate place to ask this? though i think you've answered it for me already. the turns are lightly glued together, i already unwrapped one before deciding i should ask this and confirm. it unwrapped without much effort. normally i would just do it and see what happens but its not my vacuum.

Comment: funny "repair" was a keyword in the system so i guess i assumed this is something that is asked here. it rejected some of my other keywords like "brushed-ac-motor" so i had to resort to using dc

Comment: no need to balance the two sides. the repair keyword does look inviting doesn't it, I wonder how it's meant to be used?

Comment: Without going to help and refreshing the exact language, repair of electronic systems that you have some understanding of (often including schematics, etc.) rather than vague consumer-device repairs where no understanding of the device and how it should work has been developed by the questioner. This has enough gray area that it's not been closed in two hours, but it probably will be, ultimately, at a guess. There's also a general ban on consumer electronics unless modifying them for some other purpose. Visit the help section.

Comment: There's no reason to close this question. It meets the criteria for valid repair questions on this site.

Comment: well in fairness i think so far my understanding is on the mark, if anything im being overly careful about my understanding. also, this is a question about the theory as well as I was curious of the potential effects on the windings. i suppose i could close it myself or edit the question slightly and it would meet your criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *delicate electromagnetic balance*, especially in brushed motors. The logic is simple: there were (for example) 200 turns, you removed 2 turns. This means 1% reduction in turns. By the first approximation, the motor will run 1% faster, the stall torque will rise by 1%, and heat output will go up up by 1%. You are likely not going to notice either of this.

Note: these calculations are approximate and are only valid when the change is very small; if you remove, say, a quarter of total number of turns, you will need to perform a much more complex calculation.

Comment: The motors used in vacuum cleaners are of the "universal" type; the armature and stator coils are wired in series. There is no particular design speed; indeed, the speed varies widely depending on how much air is flowing. *Unwinding* (not removing) a turn from each coil does not materially change the total circuit *resistance*, but it does reduce the ampere-turns of the stator, *reducing* the available torque and speed very slightly.